# @Inject giving null pointer exception in cucumber guice

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dependency-injection, cucumber, guice, inject

```
@ScenarioScoped
public class TestTempData
{

}
```

*@Inject TestTempData tmpData* works >>>> FINE >>>> in below class

```
public class MyStepDefClass

{

@Inject
TestTempData tmpData;
@Inject
CreateWebDriver driver;

@When("Navigating to url {string}")
public void navigateTo(String url)
{
driver.getDriver.get(url)
}
}
```

**But in below class ######### *@Inject TestTempData tmpData* is giving - Null Pointer Exception**

```
        @ScenarioScoped
        public class CreateWebDriver {
        
        
          @Inject
            TestTempData tmpData; //**Returning null**
        public WebDriver driver;
        
        public CreateWebDriver ()
        {
        
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://hub-address:4444/wd/hub")
    
       System.out.println(tmpData); // **Throwing Null pointer Exception** 
        
        }
        }
```